# Cocoa-track the menu of/inject options into itunes

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa, itunes

Is there a way I can inject menu items into itunes or detect when menu items are pressed. I have an itunes plugin that executes code when iTunes launches, but how can I use that to detect menu item clicks or possibly inject new menu item options? For example adding a new contextual menu item when you right click on a library item, or detecting when the users clicks "Like" from the Ping menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever functionality is not provided by an app's scripting bridge would only be accessible by hackery.

iTunes a Carbon app, not Cocoa, so that's more for you to learn about. iTunes even uses a call to ptrace(), passing PT_DENY_ATTACH to prevent you attaching a debugger to snoop around at runtime as well.

In other words, this is by no means an easy thing to do.